# R: sample() command subject to a constraint

Tags: r

I am trying to randomly sample 7 numbers from 0 to 7 (with replacement), but subject to the constraint that the numbers chosen add up to 7. So for instance, the output 0 1 1 2 3 0 0 is okay, but the output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 is not. Is there a way to use the sample command with added constraints?

I intend to use the replicate() function with the sample command as an argument, to return a list of N different vectors form the sample command. The way I am currently using the sample command (without any constraints), I need N to be very large in order to get as many possible vectors that sum to exactly 7 as possible. I figure there must be an easier way to do this!

Here is my code for that part:

```
x <- replicate(100000, sample(0:7, 7, replace=T))
```

Ideally, I want 10,000 or 100,000 vectors in x to sum to 7, but would need an enormous N value to do this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's exactly what I did originally. I took a subset of this x variable, but with N=100000, the subset was still very small. The subset is even pretty small with N=1000000, not to mention it takes a while to run!

Comment: You might need to use combinations **if** you want a uniform sample from the set of all possible combinations...

Comment: `partitions::parts(7)` gives you all the partitions (ways to break an integer into a sum), which might be a component of the answer ...

Comment: This is probably going to be painfully slow, but: `while (sum(x <- sample(0:7, 7, replace=T)) != 7) {}`.

Comment: `partitions::compositions(7,7)` will directly get you all of the possible 7-part partitions, which is what you are wanting. (Try e.g. `partitions::compositions(3,3)` to see the layout of the matrix so returned.)

Comment: I find it quite interesting that there are several good answers which use direct approaches.  In the general case of sampling to fit an arbitrary distribution, often the only approach is to toss out the tries which don't "fit," (see "importance sampling" and similar methods)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - that's what I originally suggested but it likely would have been very inefficient considering the number of desired "fits"

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891547/r-generating-all-permutations-of-n-weights-in-multiples-of-p.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make sure you're sampling uniformly, you could just generate all the permutations and limit to those that sum to 7:

```
library(gtools)
perms <- permutations(8, 7, 0:7, repeats.allowed=T)
perms7 <- perms[rowSums(perms) == 7,]
```

From `nrow(perms7)`, we see there are only 1716 possible permutations that sum to 7. Now you can uniformly sample from the permutations:

```
set.seed(144)
my.perms <- perms7[sample(nrow(perms7), 100000, replace=T),]
head(my.perms)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    0    0    0    2    5    0    0
# [2,]    1    3    0    1    2    0    0
# [3,]    1    4    1    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    0    0    3    0    3    0
# [5,]    0    2    0    0    0    5    0
# [6,]    1    1    2    0    0    2    1
```

An advantage of this approach is that it's easy to see that we're sampling uniformly at random. Also, it's quite quick -- building `perms7` took 0.3 seconds on my computer and building a 1 million-row `my.perms` took 0.04 seconds. If you need to draw many vectors this will be quite a bit quicker than a recursive approach because you're just using matrix indexing into `perms7` instead of generating each vector separately.

Here's a distribution of counts of numbers in the sample:

```
#      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
# 323347 188162 102812  51344  22811   8629   2472    423
```

Answer (score 8):

Start with all zeroes, add one to any element, do 7 times:

```
sumTo = function(){
    v = rep(0,7)
    for(i in 1:7){
        addTo=sample(7)[1]
        v[addTo]=v[addTo]+1
    }
    v
}
```

Or equivalently, just choose which of the 7 elements you are going to increment in one sample of length 7, then tabulate those, making sure you tabulate up to 7:

```
sumTo = function(){tabulate(sample(7, 7, replace = TRUE), 7)}


> sumTo()
[1] 2 1 0 0 4 0 0
> sumTo()
[1] 1 3 1 0 1 0 1
> sumTo()
[1] 1 1 0 2 1 0 2
```

I don't know if this will produce a uniform sample from all possible combinations...

The distribution of individual elements over 100,000 reps is:

```
> X = replicate(100000,sumTo())
> table(X)
X
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6 
237709 277926 138810  38465   6427    627     36
```

Didn't hit a 0,0,0,0,0,7 that time!

Comment: I imagine you could write this `tabulate(sample(7, 7, replace = TRUE), 7)`.

Comment: That looks algorithmically equivalent and very neat. I suck.

Answer (score 5):

This recursive algorithm will output a distribution with a higher probability for large numbers than the other solutions. The idea is to throw a random number `y` in `0:7` in any of the seven available slots, then repeat with a random number in `0:(7-y)`, etc:

```
sample.sum <- function(x = 0:7, n = 7L, s = 7L) {
   if (n == 1) return(s)
   x <- x[x <= s]
   y <- sample(x, 1)
   sample(c(y, Recall(x, n - 1L, s - y)))
}

set.seed(123L)
sample.sum()
# [1] 0 4 0 2 0 0 1
```

Drawing 100,000 vectors took 11 seconds on my machine and here is the distribution I get:

```
#      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
# 441607  98359  50587  33364  25055  20257  16527  14244
```

Comment: replicate of a 100,000 took 8 seconds with my method, and I got a single `c(0,0,7,0,0,0,0)`!

Comment: The probability for your algorithm to get a 7 is one in 7^6 or 117,649. I guess it is up to the OP to decide what kind of distribution he wants.

Comment: There are actually 8 possible values (0-7), so there are actually 8^7=2,097,152 7-length permutations with replacement. In my answer, I found that only 1716 of them sum to 7, though, so I would have expected 58 incidences of the vector `c(0,0,7,0,0,0,0)`. Only getting one is probably evidence of not sampling uniformly.

Comment: ... or just that we are sampling in different spaces. We're all using `sample` after all, not in the same type of experiment. I wouldn't call yours more uniform than ours.

Answer (score 5):

There may be an easier and/or more elegant way, but here's a brute-force method using the [`LSPM:::.nPri`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/combinatorics.R?view=markup&revision=44&root=lspm) function. The link includes the definition for an R-only version of the algorithm, for those interested.

```
#install.packages("LSPM", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
library(LSPM)
# generate all possible permutations, since there are only ~2.1e6 of them
# (this takes < 40s on my 2.2Ghz laptop)
x <- lapply(seq_len(8^7), nPri, n=8, r=7, replace=TRUE)
# set each permutation that doesn't sum to 7 to NULL
y <- lapply(x, function(p) if(sum(p-1) != 7) NULL else p-1)
# subset all non-NULL permutations
z <- y[which(!sapply(y, is.null))]
```

Now you can sample from `z` and be assured that you're getting a permutation that sums to 7.

Comment: I see josilber suggested the same thing. I'll leave this answer ans another alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I find this question intriguing and gave it some extra thought. Another (more general) approach to (approximate) sample uniformly from all feasible solutions, without generating and storing all permutations (which is clearly not possible in the case with much more than 7 numbers), in R by `sample()`, could be a simple MCMC implementation:

```
S <- c(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0) #initial solution
N <- 100 #number of dependent samples (or burn in period)
series <- numeric(N)
for(i in 1:N){
    b <- sample(1:length(S), 2, replace=FALSE) #pick 2 elements at random
    opt <- sum(S[-b]) #sum of complementary elements
    a <- sample(0:(7-opt), 1) #sample a substistute
    S[b[1]] <- a #change elements
    S[b[2]] <- 7 - opt - a 
}
S #new sample
```

This is of course really fast for a few samples. The "distribution":

```
#"distribution" N=100.000:      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
#                            321729 189647 103206  52129  22287   8038   2532    432
```

Of course in this case, where it's actually possible to find and store all combinations, and if you want a huge sample from all feasible outcomes, just use `partitions::compositions(7, 7)`, as also suggested by Josh O'Brien in the comments, to avoid calculating all the permutations, when only a small fraction is needed:

```
perms7 <- partitions::compositions(7, 7)

>tabulate(perms7[, sample(ncol(perms7), 100000, TRUE)]+1, 8)
#"distribution" N=100.000:      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
#                            323075 188787 102328  51511  22754   8697   2413    435
```