# list all permutations of k numbers, taken from 0:k, that sums to k

Tags: r, loops, recursion, permutation

This question is closely related to another question [R:sample()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951206/r-sample-command-subject-to-a-constraint/25958730#25958730). I want to find a way in R to list all the permutations of k numbers, that sums to k, where each number is chosen from 0:k. If k=7, I can choose 7 numbers from 0,1,...,7. A feasible solution is then 0,1,2,3,1,0,0 another is 1,1,1,1,1,1,1. I don't want to generate all permutations, since if k is just fairly larger than 7 this explodes.

Of course in the k=7 example I could use the following:

```
perms7<-matrix(numeric(7*1716),ncol=7) 
count=0
for(i in 0:7)
    for(j in 0:(7-i))
        for(k in 0:(7-i-j))
            for(l in 0:(7-i-j-k))
                for(n in 0:(7-i-j-k-l))
                    for(m in 0:(7-i-j-k-l-n)){
                            res<-7-i-j-k-l-n-m
                            count<-count+1
                            perms7[count,]<-c(i,j,k,l,n,m,res)
                        }
head(perms7,10)
```

But how can I generalize this approach to account for any k without having to write (k-1) loops?
I tried to come up with a recursive scheme:

```
perms7<-matrix(numeric(7*1716),ncol=7) #store solutions (adjustable size later)
k<-7 #size of interest
d<-0 #depth
count=0 #count of permutations
rec<-function(j,d,a){
    a<-a-j #max loop
    d<-d+1 #depth (posistion)
    for(i in 0:a ) {
        if(d<(k-1)) rec(i,d,a)
        count<<-count+1
        perms7[count,d]<<-i
        perms7[count,k]<<-k-sum(perms7[count,-k])
    }
}
rec(0,0,k)
```

But got stuck, and I'm not quite sure this is the right way to go. Wonder if there is any "magic" R function that is neat for this (though very specific) problem or just part of it.

In the k=7 case, all the 2.097.152 permutations and the 1.716 that sum to k=7 can be found by:

```
library(gtools)
k=7
perms <- permutations(k+1, k, 0:k, repeats.allowed=T) #all permutations
perms.k <- perms[rowSums(perms) == k,] #permutations which sums to k
```

for k=8 there are 43.046.721 permutations but I only want to list the 6.435.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe this is related to the Tower of Hanoi problem. Packages `fun` and `ref` have functions for solving this.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the Tower of Hanoi problem, can you please elaborate? Basically I just need to calculate the cardinality of a hyperplane in in Z^k.

Comment: It is the space of all possible states of a k-tile, k-peg ToH. Obviously an optimal solution to ToH will not seek to traverse all states, but if you look for the maximally suboptimal solution you should get your answer.

Comment: ahh I get your idea with a ToH of k-tiles,k-pegs and no distinction between tiles. But then I'm back to the issue of somehow listing this space, I will look into the recommended packages for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: BTW,  those are not "permutations,"   since strictly speaking you have to permute all elements of a given set.  Just being a nitpicking mathematician here.  What you're doing is sort of selecting various permutations of subsets of a "multiset" which contains seven repeats of each of 0:7  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Nitpicking is more than welcome! I of course agree, think the misuse sneaked itself in with `permutations()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a package for that...

```
require( partitions )
parts(7)                                 
#[1,] 7 6 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 1
#[2,] 0 1 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 1
#[3,] 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1
#[4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
#[5,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
#[6,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
#[7,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

You appear to be looking for `compositions()`. e.g. for *k=4*:

```
parts(4)

#[1,] 4 3 2 2 1
#[2,] 0 1 2 1 1
#[3,] 0 0 0 1 1
#[4,] 0 0 0 0 1

compositions(4,4)                                                                          
#[1,] 4 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
#[2,] 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#[3,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 0
#[4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

And just to check your math... :-)

```
ncol(compositions(8,8))
#[1] 6435
```

Comment: This is very neat. I will look into how compositions() works to ensure it doesn't just calculate all permutations and then subsets. Thank you!

Comment: @J.R. it's very quick! You will need to download the source as I think you need to check the C function `allblockparts` in the pacakge.

Comment: Yep it works great, so I'm quite confident it is not listing all the permutations first! You should consider adding it as a solution to the linked question mentioned at the beginning. I will take a look at the `allblockparts`. Thank you, again!

Comment: @J.R. It looks like Josh O'Brien did in the comments already. Feel free to add the answer yourself though. It's encouraged.

Comment: ahh you are right. Missed it! But now I have a solution that works great and go to for the implementation behind.

Comment: Cool - always fun to be introduced to a package I hadn't seen yet.