# sample integer values with specified mean

Tags: r, random, mean

I want to generate a sample of integer numbers in R with a specified mean. 
I used `mu+sd*scale(rnorm(n))` to generate a sample of `n` values that has exactly the mean=`mu`
but this generates floating-point values; I would like to generate integer values instead. For example, I would like to generate a sample of mean=4. My sample size `n`=5, an example of generated values would be {2,6,4,3,5}.
Any ideas on how to do this in R while satisfying the constraint of a specific value of the mean?

Comment: this could be impossible, depending on your specifications.  For example, if the specified mean is irrational, you'll never be able to achieve it with a sample of integers ... can you give a specific example?

Comment: if you reframe the question as "choose n numbers that sum to m*n", the question is (almost?) identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951206/r-sample-command-subject-to-a-constraint (but harder since you are using larger values ...)

Comment: What is your sample space and are you allowed to select integers more than once? Put differently, what are the `x` and `replace` in `sample(x, n , replace)`?

Comment: My sample space is all integer values and no they are not allowed to select integers more than once.

Comment: Without specifying the distribution you are interested in, there is no specific solution to the question. Even a deterministic resolution is acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

Picking `n` values with a mean of `m` is equivalent to picking `n` values that sum to `m*n`.  (I'm assuming you're going to stick to *positive* integers -- otherwise things get much harder!) Here is a solution based on sampling partitions (sets of values that add up to the desired total) uniformly, but I'm not sure it's what you want, since it doesn't sample uniformly over *values*, but over *partitions* ... perhaps someone else can do better, or figure out how to reweight the samples.

This brute-force solution will also probably fail for cases much larger than your example (there are 627 partitions for a total of 20, 5604 for a total of 30, 37338 for a total of 40 ...)

```
m <- 4
n <- 5
library("partitions")    
pp <- parts(m*n) ## all sets of integers that sum to m*n (=20 here)
## restrict to partitions with exactly n (=5) non-zero values.
pp5 <- pp[1:5,colSums(pp>0)==n]
set.seed(101) ## for reproducibility
## sample uniformly from this set
pp5[,sample(ncol(pp5),size=1)]  ## 9, 5, 4, 1, 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for your help. I understood the idea and the script works perfectly. Could you explain why you added set.seed(101)?

Comment: just so the results would be reproducible.