# take a sample that has a specific mean

Tags: r, sample

Let's say I have a population like {1,2,3, ..., 23} and I want to generate a sample so that the sample's mean equals 6.

I tried to use the `sample` function, using a custom probability vector, but it didn't work:

```
population <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
mean(population)
minimum <- min(population)
maximum <- max(population)
amplitude <- maximum - minimum 
expected <- 6
n <- length(population)
prob.vector = rep(expected, each=n)
for(i in seq(1, n)) {
  if(expected > population[i]) {
    prob.vector[i] <- (i - minimum) / (expected - minimum)
  } else {
    prob.vector[i] <- (maximum - i) / (maximum - expected)
  }
}
sample.size <- 5
sample <- sample(population, sample.size, prob = prob.vector)
mean(sample)
```

The mean of the sample is about the mean of the population (oscillates around 12), and I wanted it to be around 6.

A good sample would be:

- {3,5,6,8,9}, mean=6.2
- {2,3,4,8,9}, mean=5.6

The problem is different from [sample integer values in R with specific mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569456/sample-integer-values-in-r-with-specific-mean) because I have a specific population and I can't just generate arbitrary real numbers, they must be inside the population.

The plot of the probability vector:
[image: plot]

Comment: Not a duplicate, added explanation why.

Comment: can you give an example of the sample which will have a mean of six?

Comment: @Onyambu, added

Comment: @akrun Why have you marked it as duplicate, did you see I added the explanation why it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @banan3'14  I find a dupe link and marked as duplicate.  I reopened it.  Didn't see the comments below

Comment: @Henrik Unfortunately not. I don't want to simulate data, I have to sample it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
m = local({b=combn(1:23,5);
           d = colMeans(b);
           e = b[,d>5.5 &d<6.5];
           function()sample(e[,sample(ncol(e),1)])})
m()
[1] 8 5 6 9 3
m()
[1]  6  4  5  3 13
```

breakdown:

```
b=combn(1:23,5) # combine the numbers into 5
d = colMeans(b) # find all the means
e = b[,d>5.5 &d<6.5] # select only the means that are within a 0.5 range of 6
sample(e[,sample(ncol(e),1)]) # sample the values the you need
```

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! Could you give a little explanation, what it all means, though? I will understand if you don't (I might just have to read through the documentation and find out what `local` and other functions mean).

Comment: i did combinations. Combining 5 values from 1:23. Then found all the means of these cobinations. then  select randomly  those that are between 5.5 and 6.5 and then randomize them

Comment: Now I see. But in my real case scenario, I have population size 800 and sample size 100 (too large for generating all combinations). Hmm, perhaps I'll do Monte Carlo

Comment: but if your sample size is 100, there is no way to get 6 as the mean since the minimum mean can be 50.5 given that it is sampling with no replacement.ie if you are lucky enough to just sample 1:100 values with no value greater than 100. `mean(1:100)=50.5`

Comment: In my real case, I don't have natural numbers :) I have real numbers with mean around 144 and the average of the sample has to be around 140.

Comment: then in that case a while loop can be helpfu;