# Generate combinations of values which sum to one, sorted in descending order

Tags: r

Do you know a more efficient way to generate a matrix holding all unique combinations of "weights" (let weights be w and 0 <= w <= 1, and values of w are separated by steps of 0.1), such that the weights sum to one AND the first is the highest, the last the lowest weight.

Here is code that does the job, but it seems inefficient to delete rows:

```
# generate combinations of weights such that w1 >= w2 >= w3 ...
w = seq(0, 1, 0.1) #weights 0, 0.1, ..., 0.9, 1
w = expand.grid(w, w, w, KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE) #all combinations of 3 weights
w = w[rowSums(w) == 1, ] #make sure the weights sum to one
w = w[!(w[, 1] < w[, 2] | w[, 2] < w[, 3]),] #make sure w1 >= w2 >= w3 ...

w    
#     Var1 Var2 Var3
# 11   1.0  0.0  0.0
# 21   0.9  0.1  0.0
# 31   0.8  0.2  0.0
# 41   0.7  0.3  0.0
# 51   0.6  0.4  0.0
# 61   0.5  0.5  0.0
# 141  0.8  0.1  0.1
# 151  0.7  0.2  0.1
# 171  0.5  0.4  0.1
# 271  0.6  0.2  0.2
# 281  0.5  0.3  0.2
# 291  0.4  0.4  0.2
# 401  0.4  0.3  0.3
```

Let me add some more general info:
In this problem (3 weights in the above order) the upper limits for the first, second, third values are as follows:

- the first number can minimally be 1 for the combination (1, 0, 0)
- the second number can maximally be 1/2 for the combination (1/2, 1/2, 0)
- the third number can maximally be 1/3 for the combination (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)

Comment: In the example output you showed the weights do not sum to one ... From your code I assume that they are supposed to sum to `<= 1`. If this is the case you should edit your question.

Comment: Also the three points at the end are redundant since they follow from the requirement that the first element in each row must be the greatest.

Comment: @user2706569 edited the question, was a typo.

Comment: @Seamus O'Baired: your comment is logically true, sure! But a good question is not necessarily the least redundant question, right? It is the most clear question. Thus, I figure, explicicating things is more important than being least redundant.

Comment: What distribution of those variables do you expect?

Comment: For some reason (0.6,0.3,0.1) is missing.

Comment: Related Q&A, although the sorting part is not explicit in the Q: [R: Generating all permutations of N weights in multiples of P](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891547/r-generating-all-permutations-of-n-weights-in-multiples-of-p/).

Comment: I think I got the reason why (0.6,0.3,0.3) is missing. "seq(0,1,0.1)" is not very accurate. "(0:10)/10" is a better choice. Then "JBJ"s solution contains as many triples as "Henrik"s solution.

Comment: "0 <= w <= 1, and values of w are separated by steps of 0.1" restricts the weights to those in the example. Then efficiency wouldn't be a problem. What are really the restrictions on the weights you want to work with? Your inefficient code handles any set of weights. "Henrik"s efficient solution silently assumes that the weights are equidistant, as in the example.

Comment: Thanks (sorry for the delay). @mra68 Assuming equal spacing is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-`base` possibility:

```
library(partitions)

step <- 0.1
n_weights <- 3

t(restrictedparts(n = 1/step, m = n_weights) * step)
#  [1,] 1.0 0.0 0.0
#  [2,] 0.9 0.1 0.0
#  [3,] 0.8 0.2 0.0
#  [4,] 0.7 0.3 0.0
#  [5,] 0.6 0.4 0.0
#  [6,] 0.5 0.5 0.0
#  [7,] 0.8 0.1 0.1
#  [8,] 0.7 0.2 0.1
#  [9,] 0.6 0.3 0.1
# [10,] 0.5 0.4 0.1
# [11,] 0.6 0.2 0.2
# [12,] 0.5 0.3 0.2
# [13,] 0.4 0.4 0.2
# [14,] 0.4 0.3 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

General purpose function with standard packages:

```
# Generate weights matrix with noWeights columns and noRows rows.
# Each row of this matrix contains sorted decremental weights summing up to 1.0.
generateWeights = function(noWeights,
                           noRows,
                           distribution = runif,
                           rounding = function(x){ round(x, 1) })
{
  generator = function()
  {
    x = distribution (noWeights);
    x = x/sum(x);
    sort(rounding(x), decreasing = T)
  } 
  t(replicate(noRows, generator()))
}

# example of use
generateWeights(3, 10)
```

Comment: Takes quite a lot of adjustment before it runs …

Comment: Where are "rows" and "cols" defined? Why are "noWeights" and "noRows" unused? Is "gen" supposed to be equal to "generateWeights"?

Comment: sorry for that. fixed.

Comment: In this case "genarateWeights(3,10) yields only 10 of the 13 triples.

Comment: I think I don't get last of your comments.

Comment: How many triples do you expect? "JBJ"s code yields 13, "Henrik"s code 14 triples. The correct number is 14, I guess.

Comment: Its generateWeights parameter. In example - its set to 10.

Comment: "Henrik"s answer shows that we want 14 triples, each of them summing up to 1. "genrateWeights(3,10)" yields only 10 triples. "generateWeights(3,14)" yields 14 triples, but not all of them sum up to 1.