# R: How do I generate a data frame with each rowSum is 1

Tags: r, combinations

I have a dataframe with 15 columns and 11 rows each. Row values go from 0.0 to 1.0 increments of 0.1. What I'd like to do is generate all combinations but only keep the combinations that sum up to 1 for each row. I tried using expand.grid but with 15 columns obviously I run out of memory.

The following code works for 5 columns for example, but I need to do the same for 15 or 20 columns.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(seq(0.0,1.0,by=0.1),5), 11, 5))
df.grid <- expand.grid(df)
df.grid[which(rowSums(df.grid)==1),]
```

I am sure there is a simple way to do this but I am new to R.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: btw, I can't use multiple loops because the number of columns is not fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Really, you only need one copy of each number greater than .5, two of each greater than 1/3, three greater than .25, etc., so it may be simpler to do it by hand with `combn`.

Comment: I was thinking you can generate the values into a vector like you did but sample them randomly with `sample` and have `replace=T`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, you are correct that if I sum up every row, some rows will have values greater than 1 and I'd like to throw them out and keep only the ones that sum up to 1. if that means some columns will have zeros as their values. 

Ok. I see my mistake. I should have said 0 to 1 in increments of 0.1. I will correct the question above.

Comment: Refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617501/all-possible-combinations-of-a-set-that-sum-to-a-target-value) or you could use `combn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found an answer from one of the suggested posts on the right. I am still checking. but here is the answer.

```
library("partitions")
numColumns <- 15 
numIncrements <- 10
weights <- t(compositions(n=numIncrements, m=numColumns, include.zero=TRUE)/numIncrements)
weights
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to minimize the work your computer needs to do, because you're dealing with a LOT of combinations here. Firstly, limit the set of numbers you're operating on to the minimal set. Given that `1` already sums to 1, you don't want more than one `1` in your set. On the other end, you don't want more than ten `0.1`s. You can get the full set, then, by taking the floor of the result of dividing 1 by the sequence of unique numbers:

```
x <- seq(.1, 1, by = .1)    # initialize 0.1:1 sequence
x <- rep(x, floor(1/x))    # repeat minimal set for all combinations
```

which is only 27 numbers:

```
> x
 [1] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6
[24] 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

Now you need to loop `combn` over the possible number of terms in the combination, which will run from 1 to `1/min(x)`, i.e. 10. We can then index down to the rows where `colSums == 1` (`combn` returns combinations as columns):

```
lapply(seq_len(1/min(x)), function(y){z <- combn(x, y); z[,colSums(z) == 1]})
```

This works in not unreasonable time given the size (37 seconds on my laptop to produce a 1Mb list of 10 matrices), but it still returns a *lot* of duplicate combinations because each iteration contains more copies of some numbers than necessary; e.g. when picking 3, there's no point of a second `0.5`, or `0.2 0.3 0.5` will be returned twice.

It's also not in a terribly convenient format, as all the matrices have different dimensions. If we add a function to `combn` to add `NA`s so every combination has a length of 10, the `lapply` takes 2-3 times as long, but it does allow us to easily combine them with `do.call(rbind, ... )` and thus easily use `unique.matrix` to reduce it to unique combinations.

```
x <- seq(.1, 1, by = .1)    # initialize 0.1:1 sequence
x <- rep(x, floor(1/x))    # repeat minimal set for all combinations
results <- lapply(seq_len(max(x)/min(x)), function(y){
  # calculate combinations; fill lengths to 10 with NA to allow easy joining later
  z <- combn(x, y, function(x){c(x, rep(NA, 10 - y))})
  z[,colSums(z, na.rm = TRUE) == 1]})    # chop to combinations with sum == 1
results <- do.call(cbind, results)    # combine 10 matrices
results <- unique.matrix(results, MARGIN = 2)    # remove remaining repeats
```

Alternately, you could do a second `lapply` with `unique.matrix` and insert the `NA`s after, which would likely be faster, but the version above is a nice bridge case for what follows, though.

If we optimize the list of possibly useful numbers to combine in our loop, we can calculate many, many fewer combinations, and thus speed up the process dramatically, to the point where it executes near-instantaneously. There will still be some repeats, as some numbers need to be repeated more for certain combinations than others, but we can use the above approach to simplify:

```
results <- lapply(seq_len(10), function(y){
  x <- seq(.1, 1, by = .1)    # initialize 0.1:1 sequence
  # calculate minimum repititions of each number; .099 to avoid floating point error
  reps <- ifelse(y <= floor((1 - .1 * (y - 1)) / (x - .099)),
                 ifelse(y * x == 1, y, y - 1), 
                 floor((1 - .1 * (y - 1)) / (x - .099)) )
  x <- rep(x, reps)    # build set with necessary repeats
  # calculate combinations; fill lengths to 10 with NA to allow easy joining later
  z <- combn(x, y, FUN = function(x){c(x, rep(NA, 10 - y))})
  z[, colSums(z, na.rm = TRUE) == 1]    # chop to combinations with sum == 1
  })
results <- do.call(cbind, results)    # combine 10 matrices
results <- unique.matrix(results, MARGIN = 2)    # remove remaining repeats
```

Note that the `reps` expression is probably not mathematically ideal, but produces the correct sets for all 10 iterations here. (If you have a better version, please comment!)

All told, you get a matrix of 41 combinations, which you probably could have written out by hand.

```
> results
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
 [1,]    1  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.1
 [2,]   NA  0.9  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.5  0.1  0.2  0.3   0.4   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.3   0.1   0.1
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  0.8  0.7  0.6   0.5   0.6   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.1   0.2
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.7   0.6
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
      [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31]
 [1,]   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1
 [2,]   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1
 [3,]   0.3   0.4   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1
 [4,]   0.5   0.4   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.3   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.3   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1
 [5,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.6   0.5   0.4   0.4   0.3   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.2
 [6,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.5   0.4
 [7,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [8,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [9,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[10,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
      [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41]
 [1,]   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
 [2,]   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
 [3,]   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
 [4,]   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
 [5,]   0.3   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
 [6,]   0.3   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1
 [7,]    NA    NA    NA   0.4   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.2   0.1   0.1
 [8,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.3   0.2   0.1   0.1
 [9,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.2   0.1
[10,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.1
```

A little anticlimactic, really.

Comment: alistaire, Thank you so much for the nice explanation. Agree that i should minimize the work. In my case I need to go one step further. I have a group of 10 elements that I need to assign these weights to, to find the best weight combination. Which means the 41 unique weight combinations from your example will need to be applied to 10 different elements with each element at any of the 10 slots. Hence i was looking for all combinations.

Comment: Obviously, running through all combinations takes a long time. So I plan to sample the combinations for a reasonable amount of time to come up with the best combination in that time. Generating all combinations is more for educational purposes because I was not sure how to do it in case if I wanted to run through all combinations for smaller numbers.