# Creating a combination of every possible changing weight in R

Tags: r

I am wondering if R has a function that performs the following:

```
weight <- function(n,x){...}
```

Inside this function it takes the number held by the variable n and creates that many columns of a new data frame. The value held by the variable x is the size of the steps that you want to change by with each new row. From there it creates output such as shown below. For example with n = 5 and x = .01

```
line 1    100    0    0     0     0
line 2   .99   .01   0     0     0
line 3   .98   .01  .01    0     0
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is an older posting. I have posted the link below

[Generate combinations of values which sum to one, sorted in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672736/generate-combinations-of-values-which-sum-to-one-sorted-in-descending-order?lq=1)